# Incorporating Geolocation into Javascript Weather Function

Tags: javascript, geolocation, weather

I'm trying to set up this app from simpleweather to use GeoLocation. I have done a fair bit of google-fu, but nothing seems to be working.

Basically instead of using the location name or woeID (near the top), I'd like it to use the browser's Geolocation. Any tips?

```js
         // Docs at http://simpleweatherjs.com
        var updateWeather = function() {
          $.simpleWeather({
            location: '',
            woeid: '1105779',
            unit: 'c',
            success: function(weather) {
              var skycons = new Skycons({
                "color": "white"
              });

              html = '<canvas id="weather-icon" width="128" height="128"></canvas><h2> ' + weather.temp + '&deg;' + weather.units.temp + '</h2>';
              html += '<div id="region">' + weather.city + ', ' + weather.region + '</div>';
              html += '<div>' + weather.currently + '</div>';
              html += '<div>' + weather.wind.direction + ' ' + weather.wind.speed + ' ' + weather.units.speed + '</div>';
              html += '<div><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i>  High ' + weather.high + ' <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>  Low ' + weather.low + '</div>'
              $("#weather").html(html);

              switch (parseInt(weather.code)) {
                case 0:
                  var animation = 'sleet';
                  break;
                case 1:
                  var animation = 'sleet';
                  break;
                case 2:
                  var animation = 'sleet';
                  break;
                case 3:
                  var animation = 'sleet';
                  break;
                case 4:
                  var animation = 'sleet';
                  break;
                case 5:
                  var animation = 'snow';
                  break;
                case 6:
                  var animation = 'snow';
                  break;
                case 7:
                  var animation = 'snow';
                  break;
                case 8:
                  var animation = 'snow';
                  break;
                case 9:
                  var animation = 'rain';
                  break;
                case 10:
                  var animation = 'snow';
                  break;
                case 11:
                  var animation = 'rain';
                  break;
                case 12:
                  var animation = 'rain';
                  break;
                case 13:
                  var animation = 'snow';
                  break;
                case 14:
                  var animation = 'snow';
                  break;
                case 15:
                  var animation = 'snow';
                  break;
                case 16:
                  var animation = 'snow';
                  break;
                case 17:
                  var animation = 'sleet';
                  break;
                case 18:
                  var animation = 'sleet';
                  break;
                case 19:
                  var animation = 'fog';
                  break;
                case 20:
                  var animation = 'fog';
                  break;
                case 21:
                  var animation = 'fog';
                  break;
                case 22:
                  var animation = 'fog';
                  break;
                case 23:
                  var animation = 'wind';
                  break;
                case 24:
                  var animation = 'wind';
                  break;
                case 25:
                  var animation = 'cloudy';
                  break;
                case 26:
                  var animation = 'cloudy';
                  break;
                case 27:
                  var animation = 'partly-cloudy-night';
                  break;
                case 28:
                  var animation = 'partly-cloudy-day';
                  break;
                case 29:
                  var animation = 'partly-cloudy-night';
                  break;
                case 30:
                  var animation = 'partly-cloudy-day';
                  break;
                case 31:
                  var animation = 'clear-night';
                  break;
                case 32:
                  var animation = 'clear-day';
                  break;
                case 33:
                  var animation = 'clear-night';
                  break;
                case 34:
                  var animation = 'clear-day';
                  break;
                case 35:
                  var animation = 'sleet';
                  break;
                case 36:
                  var animation = 'clear-day';
                  break;
                case 37:
                  var animation = 'sleet';
                  break;
                case 38:
                  var animation = 'sleet';
                  break;
                case 39:
                  var animation = 'sleet';
                  break;
                case 40:
                  var animation = 'rain';
                  break;
                case 41:
                  var animation = 'snow';
                  break;
                case 42:
                  var animation = 'snow';
                  break;
                case 43:
                  var animation = 'snow';
                  break;
                case 44:
                  var animation = 'partly-cloudy-day';
                  break;
                case 45:
                  var animation = 'sleet';
                  break;
                case 46:
                  var animation = 'snow';
                  break;
                case 46:
                  var animation = 'sleet';
                  break;
                default:
                  var animation = 'clear-day';
              }

              skycons.remove('weather-icon')
                // you can add a canvas by it's ID...
              console.log(animation);
              skycons.add("weather-icon", animation);

              // ...or by the canvas DOM element itself.

              // if you're using the Forecast API, you can also supply
              // strings: "partly-cloudy-day" or "rain".

              // start animation!
              skycons.play();
            },
            error: function(error) {
              $("#weather").html('<p>' + error + '</p>');
            }
          });
        };
        $(document).ready(function() {
          updateWeather();
          setInterval(updateWeather, 300000);
        });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use google geocoding API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro for this kind of purpose.

After you get the location of the user (lets assume user type their location on the input), then you put the user location to the geocoding API.

After that, you can get the corresponding latitude and longitude that you require.

Hope this helps.